# Webpack 5 devServer not loading public static files

Tags: webpack, webpack-dev-server

I have a file structure like this:

```
-node_modules
-public
--scripts
-src
```

And my **webpack.config.js**:

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = () => {
    return {
        entry: './src/index.js',
        output: {
            path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'public/scripts'),
            filename: 'bundle.js'
        },
        module: {
            rules: [
                {
                    test: /\.js$/,
                    exclude: /nodule_modules/,
                    use: {
                        loader: 'babel-loader',
                        options: {
                            presets: ['@babel/preset-env'],
                        },
                    },
                },
            ],
        },
        mode: process.env.WEBPACK_MODE || 'development',
        devServer: { 
            static: {
                directory: path.join(__dirname, 'public'),
                publicPath: '/scripts'
            },

            hot: true,
            compress: true,
            port: 3000,
        },
    };
};
```

My problem is that the browser doesn't load any content reporting: `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)` at `192.168.0.11/:1`

When I remove the `publicPath` property, the HTML is getting rendered but bundle.js isn't found.

Comment: It sounds like you're trying to use `static` to serve what webpack is bundling for you. Static should only be used to serve uncontrolled source/assets like images or any content extraneous to your development. Ex: I [_self host_](https://www.tiny.cloud/blog/get-started-with-tinymce-self-hosted/) the `tinymce` library from my root directory containing the main bundle using `devServer: {static: __dirname}`

Answer (score 2):

I hope this helps those who are looking for the answer. On webpack 5, we can set multiple paths to be public, just replacing the object with a list.

```
{
      ...
      devServer: {
        static: [
          path.join(__dirname, "build"),
          path.join(__dirname, "scripts"),
        ],
}
```

Comment: bug in windows. cannot start webpack dev server when `config.devServer.static` is set

Comment: I'm sorry, but I cannot help if I don't have more information.
The structure can be found on: [webpack dev-server](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/#devserverstatic).
I'm not sure how are you using the configuration, but the `config` is not required, so I'm wondering if you wrote only to make an example of: ```javascript
module.exports = {
  devServer: {
    static: false,
  },
};```

Comment: fixed, the errors caught when I using forwardslash (/) instead backslash (\\) in windows. Now it works when setting multiple public folder. Look at https://github.com/dimaslanjaka/hexo-webpack/blob/af5308e5b57ac9e37467e1e6dde4fafdce6086db/config/webpack.dev.js#L35

Comment: Nice that you found the issue. For that reason the use of `path.join` is recommended. to avoid parsing '/' or '\'